# Is adding methods in a subclass poor design?

Tags: java, design

Let's say we have a abstract super class `A` with abstract method `m1` and `m2`. `B` inherits from `A`, overrides `m1` and `m2` and defines a new public method `m3`. Since to access `m3` we have to cast `B and this requires the usage of`instanceof` operator:

```
A a = new B();
if(a instanceof B) {
  B b = (B) a;
  b.m3();
}
```

Does this mean that adding `m3` was a poor design decision and all subclasses should stick to the interface defined in the superclass without adding new methods ? In fact, ideally, we should always program against the interface so even casting to a subtype would be poor design.

Comment: Reasoning about such design decisions by looking at nonsensical class names A and B, nonsensical method names m1, m2, m3 and no use case or real world context is  purely speculative and IMHO not very sensible. And design is never just "good", "bad" or "poor", you need to know your design goals to evaluate the quality of a design.

Comment: I'm guessing that what you are asking is why have methods that are only defined in a subclass (like your m3), but aren't available through the base class interface. It's true that the need to cast indicates that there *could* be something wrong with the design (i.e., that you've conceptualized the abstraction in the wrong way), but that's not always the case. But there doesn't need to be casting involved - you can create an object of type B, call m3 to configure something, and then pass it to some code that expects A. Or you can use it non-polymorphically.

Comment: We can all just guess. That's the problem with the question (and was pointed out by @Doc).

Comment: You cannot avoid casting like you cannot avoid if/else, cyclomatic complexity. What a good design does is reduce them as much as possible.

Comment: I might argue that designing a base class to know about specific subclasses introduces a circular dependency and breaks encapsulation.  Two things that are bad object orientated design problems.  If the base class is designed to be extended, i.e. by calling a virtual method `m3()` with a default empty implementation does not require the base class to know about it's children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that adding m3 was a poor design decision and all subclasses should stick to the interface defined in the superclass without adding new methods ? In fact, ideally, we should always program against the interface so even casting to a subtype would be poor design.

Yes, that indicates a design flaw.

The usual way to solve such problems (extending on existing interfaces) is to intcroduce another interface that defines `m3` (say `C`), and let `B` inherit from `A` while also implementing the extra interface.
Thus `B` can be used in any contexts that require `A`, and additionally be used everywhere when `C` is required.

The necessity of explicit casting should be avoided by all means.

Answer (score 2):

> Is adding methods in a subclass poor design?

No, it isn't, but your claim is wrong:

> Since to access m3 we have to cast B and this requires the usage of instanceof operator:

In your example you are calling m3 directly after instantiation, so the if-condition is always true:

```
A a = new B(); 
if(a instanceof B) 
{ 
    B b = (B) a; b.m3(); 
}
```

The problem is that in the first line you are prematurely up-casting (from B to A), just to downcast later.
Your could easily be rewritten as:

```
B b = new B();
b.m3(); 
A a = b;
```

Now you are only up-casting at the end, after you made all B-specific method calls.
Your example might be overly simplified and construction of B and the call of m3 might not be in the same method, but the principle is the same: Don't up-cast to the parent class, if you expect an instance of a specific sub-class.

Comment: I believe that POV at the problem is a bit too short cut. At least the OP needs to provide a better example of what they really want to achieve.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree, while I a am answering the question as stated, it might not actually help the OP. The question as asked is most likely too abstract.
I am happy to expand on the answer, when there is more detail. I believe the principle behind the answer is likely to stay the same: Don't upcast too early.
I am going to edit my answer to elaborate more on the principle, rather the concrete code.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is something that programmers strive to avoid. This is not only because it indicates a weakness in the static typing of the code, but because casts can also simply be tedious to use and make code less readable.

```
A a = new B();

if(a instanceof B) { 
    B b = (B) a;
    b.m3(); 
}
```

> Is adding methods in a subclass poor design?

Of course not. In fact adding extra behavior is one major advantage of inheritance for OOP language.

Your example is not a good example to confront the actual problem. I am just adding new line to make the concern clear,

```
A a = new B();

// many instructions here

if(a instanceof B) { 
    B b = (B) a;
    b.m3(); 
}
```

Now, for a simple program like yours, it seems inheritance making no sense. But in reality those casting should be done in a single common business class to avoid reusing in many other classes later. Casting seems like to be similar to `cyclomatic complexity` IMHO. Thus,

We cannot program without `if/else/switch` but better design minimizes them. Similarly we cannot avoid casting but a good design reduces them.

Moreover, as *Doc Brown* [commented](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/9113/doc-brown),

> And design is never just "good", "bad" or "poor", you need to know your design goals to evaluate the quality of a design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any programming concept is inherently good or bad. But I do make one exception. And that is reflection for non-debugging applications.

Ask yourself why you need the `instanceof` operator. Is it that you're accessing the items in a foreach loop like this:

```
for (A a : aList) {
    if(a instanceof B) {
        B b = (B) a;
        b.m3();
    }
}
```

Perhaps it is better to maintain a dedicated loop of `B`'s. Or are you trying to do two things at once?

```
for (A a : aList) {
    a.m1()
    if(a instanceof B) {
        B b = (B) a;
        b.m3();
    }
}
```

Perhaps it would be better to make `m1()` virtual (that is override it in `B`). Or if that's too much work you can make `m1()` call a protected `m3()` that is empty except in `B` which overrides it. And I'd name it something like `tryDoM3()`. Something like:

```
public class A {
    public void m1() {
        doStuff();
        tryDoM3();
        doMoreStuff();
    }

    protected void tryDoM3() {}
}
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected void tryDoM3() {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

And lastly if you want to call `m1()` and then do something else locally and then call `m3()` to clean up or something you could do something like.

```
for (A a : aList) {
    a.m1()
    doSomeStuffLocally()
    a.tryDoM3()
}
```

Instead where `tryDoM3()` is possibly empty as described above.